# Where to ask a technology-based linguistics question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a technology-based linguistics question, but I don't know where to ask it.

> Which is grammatically correct? 'a .exe file' or 'an .exe file'?

Would this fall under [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), or somewhere else?

Comment: Just FYI, this general question has been already answered on ELU and [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/328/an-hour-or-a-hour).

Comment: @Catija I'm not asking due to the pronunciation of "exe". I'm asking because I'm not sure if you read the phrase as "an e-x-e" or "a (dot) e-x-e"

Comment: That's not clear from your example as the only difference is a vs an. Most people I know don't pronounce the dot but there's no one answer to that... you pick a or an based on your choice of pronunciation in that case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a question about grammar. It doesn't matter if it mentions executable files, rockets, pets, or marshmallows.

So it's either [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) or [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), depending on the level.

It would be off-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), since it's not related to a software/hardware issue.

[Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) is more about language theory in general, not about specific English grammar questions.

Comment: To be a bit of a nitpick, it's not that much about grammar, but pronunciation. If I'm not mistaken, that is.

Comment: @M.A.R. it's about choosing between "a" and "an" - it's a grammatical rule that depends on the end pronunciation of the word rather than on whether it starts with a consonant or a vowel. It's only a pronunciation question because the written grammar depends on pronunciation.

Comment: I can decide whether you meant that this is about syntax, or that it is about morphology. Whichever of the two you meant, I'm having trouble seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my specific question has already been answered on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

See ["An .exe or a .exe"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/222494/224606)